# Should I care about Compiler when I have created Library/Framework of my Project and running on Different Compiler?

Tags: ios, objective-c, llvm, libraries, llvm-gcc

I have created iOS Library/Framework (static) of my project using **LLVM GCC compiler** with NON-ARC build. Now I want to use this Library in my newer projects with Apple **LLVM Compiler with ARC compliance**.

Should I worry about converting my Library project in Apple LLVM Compiler with ARC? What/Where will be the impact areas I should concern?

My primary analysis says that i am able to use my LLVM GCC Library in Apple LLVM Compiler. But not satisfied with result.

Please suggest your analysis and conclusions. Thanks

**EDIT:**

Note that `class_copyPropertyList` method's behavior is got changed with Apple LLVM Compiler. Prior in LLVM GCC Compiler this method returns all the List of variables in **Reverse order** declared in interface. But from Apple LLVM Compiler this method returns in **same Sequence** as declared in Interface.

**IMPORTANT:** Though this behavior is changed with **Apple LLVM Compiler**, this behavior is not affected in Library. But when I use to run the sample project including Library project (Not library but its project) then This method gives me **WRONG** result.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To answer your question, you don't need to upgrade...yet. If you have the time I would go ahead and make your library ARC compliant.

***Here's what could happen***: Your code will not compile or your code could receive a bunch of warnings. You can put exceptions in your build settings to mark your library non ARC compliant. Which should cause any build/run time issues to go away.

Comment: Hi Benny, thanks your feedback. But I found some odd behavior with Compiler change. Please see my Edited section. Can you please give any feedback on the same??

Comment: I'm not sure it's odd, but good that you are able to recognize the issue. Your issue is a great example that even if it compiles fine it may handle fundamental aspects differently when using different compilers. Since you know the issue it shouldn't be too hard to fix.